# Cannot find lmdb package after installing it

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, lmdb

I installed `lmdb` in my anaconda distribution:

```
conda install lmdb
```

I could not import `lmdb` within python

```
import lmdb
```

I did a search, lmdb was installed in `pkg\lmdb-0.9.21-h6538335_1`

I later used `pip` to install `lmdb`

```
pip install lmdb
```

When I try to import it within, it is available.
pip install lmdb into

- `Lib\site-packages\lmdb-0.9.3-dist-info` and
- `Lib\site-packages\lmdb`

How to use `conda install` to install `lmdb` under `Lib\site-packages`?

Comment: You are likely installing `lmbd` into a different environment than the one you are running `import lmdb` in

Comment: I actually did my work before posting. It may be environment issue but I actually install lmdb globally

    `condo install lmdb`

I also run python NOT in any environment.

If I install use

    `pip install lmdb`

It allows me to access lmdb from any environment.  There are some differences between pip and condo for lmdb library.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the issue:

I need to install `lmdb` in the correct environment. I discovered the list of environments using the command

```
conda info --envs
```

which showed `base` is the only environment

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Anaconda
```

So, I installed `lmdb` in that environment

```
conda install --name base lmdb python-lmdb
```

Now, `import lmdb` works.

As in 2nd March 2018 `python-lmdb` for Windows 10 is not available. You may install using the following command

```
conda install --name base -c conda-forge python-lmdb
```

You may check out development of the issue for [`python-lmdb` here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8740#issuecomment-370183360).

The available packages and platforms could be found from [Anaconda Repository](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo).